# How do I resolve this Marketing Cloud Journey Object Activity permissions error?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am getting the following error when I am trying to create a record in Journey Builder in Marketing Cloud.
[image]
Your account does not have sufficient permissions to access this feature.

Which permissions need to be added in Marketing Cloud and/or Sales Cloud to enable this for my user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to configure your journey with a user that has been integrated with the core platform. [Here's the doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000357850&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1) on resolving the above error.